# How can i add objects into array using reducer

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, immutability

//i need to add objects into a array using reducer for contact book

//reducer

```
const addContact = (contacts = [], action) => {
  let contactsArr = [{}];
  if (action.type = "ADD_CONTACT") {
    return [...contactsArr, action.payload];
  }
  return contacts;
};
```

actions

```
export const addContactRed = contact => {
  return {
    type: "ADD_CONTACT",
    payload: contact
  };
};


{
type:"ADD_CONTACT",
payload:{name:"xyz",phonenum:10101001}
}

{
type:"ADD_CONTACT",
payload:{name:"abc",phonenum:0101001}
}
```

//after dispatching two actions final array i want is

//contactsArr

```
[
{name:"xyz",phonenum:10101001},
{name:"abc",phonenum:0101001}
]
```

Comment: This line `if (action.type = "ADD_CONTACT") {` seems to be wrong. This is not doing comparison but assigning the value

Comment: your first code block will always add an empty object to the reducers state

Comment: yes, it is wrong it should be if(action.type==="ADD_CONTACT"). Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have ton init  let contactsArr = [{}]; It will reset the store value in your reducer. Just use the contact store variable

```
const addContact = (contacts = [], action) => {
 // if (action.type = "ADD_CONTACT") {
  if (action.type === "ADD_CONTACT") {
    return [...contacts, action.payload];
  }
  return contacts;
};
```